# Asp.Net web service: I would like to return error 403 forbidden

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, http-status-code-403

I have got a web service programmed in c#  / asp.net.

```
[WebService(Namespace = "http://example.com/")]
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
[ScriptService]
[System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]
public class Service: System.Web.Services.WebService
{

    [WebMethod]
    [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
    public Result GetData()
    {
        User user = GetUser();

        if (user.LoggedIn)
        {
            return GetData();
        }
        else
        {
            // raise exception -> return error 403
        }
    }
```

How is it possible to return error 403 out of this web service? I can throw an exception - but this shows the exeption and not his error.

Any ideas?

Comment: You return value from service only if user is 'LoggedIn' you must return that 'Result' type from that method.

Comment: and how do I return this 'Result' type ?

Comment: You declare your method to return 'Result' type. And you must return object of that type from your method. What is 'Data()'? You cant return something from only one 'if' block, because if that block is false your method will not return anything.

Comment: I thought I can raise an exceptino or something like this and then the web service would return 403

Comment: Code 401 would be more appropriate as the user could access the resource if he loggs in

Answer (score 23, accepted):

To answer the question completely - this is the code I've used (thank you strider for more information):

```
[WebService(Namespace = "http://example.com/")]
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
[ScriptService]
[System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]
public class Service: System.Web.Services.WebService
{

    [WebMethod]
    [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
    public Result GetData()
    {
        User user = GetUser();

        if (user.LoggedIn)
        {
            return GetData();
        }
        else
        {
            Context.Response.Status = "403 Forbidden"; 
            //the next line is untested - thanks to strider for this line
            Context.Response.StatusCode = 403;
            //the next line can result in a ThreadAbortException
            //Context.Response.End(); 
            Context.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest(); 
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Comment: This gives me a ThreadAbortException when used with WebMethod and ScriptMethod.

Comment: try using  Context.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest() instead of Context.Response.End()

Comment: Worth mentioning that `Response.Status = "403 Forbidden"; ` is the complete `status` that consists of `Response.StatusCode` and `Response.StatusDescription`. It might be better to use `Response.StatusDescription` instead of `Response.Status`

Comment: In my case it's called "ActionContext" instead of "Context"

Answer (score 35):

If you were using MVC you'd do the following:

```
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.Forbidden);
```

Answer (score 32):

You don't need to set both `Context.Response.Status` and `Context.Response.StatusCode`.  Simply setting

```
Context.Response.StatusCode = (int)System.Net.HttpStatusCode.Forbidden
```

will automatically set `Response.Status` for you.

Comment: It should be a comment on @bernhardrusch answer

Answer (score 7):

You can protect all your methods by placing the code in your WebService constructor.  This prevents your WebMethod from even being called:

```
public Service(): base()
{
    if (!GetUser().LoggedIn)
    {
        Context.Response.StatusCode = (int)System.Net.HttpStatusCode.Forbidden;
        Context.Response.End();
    }
}
```

Comment: Not necessarily correct....I leverage WebMethods through AJAX calls and I have to work to authenticate the user(s) through encrypted cookies

Comment: This doesn't make sense. Your constructor isn't called when your web methods are called. Refer to @bernhardrusch's answer.

Answer (score 6):

In Asp.Net Web Api 2, you'd use:

```
return new StatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.Forbidden, this);
```

Comment: This does not answer the question at all! The question was relating to a WebService and this is WebApi2

Comment: I get what you're saying, but I was fixing some legacy stuff and didn't need to know the answer to a different question that i already knew!

Comment: ok my bad ..didn't realize people would still be working on web services.

Comment: NP. Wish i wasn't!

Comment: @matt_lethargic like your profile comment! ;-) Seems legacy crap code is common in automotive field :P

Answer (score 3):

```
Context.Response.StatusCode = 403;
```

Comment: where do I get this response object [I can't access it directly]?

Comment: Context.Response.Status = "403 Forbidden";
Context.Response.End();
return null;

Comment: Context.Response.Status is a string property, +1 for @bernhardrusch. Correct property to set would be Context.Response.StatusCode if you want to just set 403, an int.

Answer (score 1):

Your web service requests will first encounter your global.asax file.  You can check & return there.

Answer (score 1):

aspnet core you can return forbidResult.  This is an IResult.

```
return new ForbidResult();
```

Answer (score 0):

Forbidden 403 would be a result of access to forbidden content on your website. I think what you want here is to return a message as part of your Result that is "User is not logged on"

Answer (score 0):

The `return Forbid();` creates a ForbidResult (Status403Forbidden by default).

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.controllerbase.forbid?view=aspnetcore-3.1