# Allow only requests from local machine in WebAPI 2

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

There are some action methods in my WebAPI 2 application where I would like to disable remote accessibility (scheduled administrative tasks). Other action methods should be publicly available. Is an `ActionFilter` the best bet in this case?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

FROM book "Pro ASP.NET MVC 4 4th edition":

```cs
public class CustomActionAttribute : FilterAttribute, IActionFilter { 
    public void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext) { 
        if (filterContext.HttpContext.Request.IsLocal) { 
            filterContext.Result = new HttpNotFoundResult(); 
        } 
    }

    public void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext) { 
        // not yet implemented 
    } 
}
```

Comment: I'm sure you'll understand how to make this example to work as desired :)

Comment: Nice answer, although, I see it a lot; I am having some troubles with the `404 Not Found` which is returned. I would say a `403 Forbidden` is more appropriate.

Comment: @Stefan there is an answer for your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5649852/asp-net-web-service-i-would-like-to-return-error-403-forbidden

Answer (score 10):

I think that cross-origin resource sharing (CORS) will help your if you have local url for your site. You can apply list of origins for public actions and only local origin for your secured actions. For example:

Local:

```cs
[EnableCors(Origins = new[] { "http://localhost", "http://sample.com" })]
public class ValuesController : ApiController
{
......
}
```

and secured:

```cs
[EnableCors(origins: "http://localhost")]
public class ValuesController : ApiController
{
......
}
```

You can find out more details by the next links: [CORS support for ASP.NET Web API](http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=CORS%20support%20for%20ASP.NET%20Web%20API) and [Scope Rules for [EnableCors]](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/enabling-cross-origin-requests-in-web-api#scope)

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion. I wouldn't have thought of doing it this way.

Comment: wouldn't this only prevent calls from a browser? Wouldn't server-side calls from off-machine still be allowed, assuming open ports and whatnot?

Comment: @user323774 I developed mobile app that used my API, and I couldn't reach my API before I allowed to enable cors attribute (EnableCorsAttribute("*", "*", "*");)

Comment: The disadvantage is that CORS requires at least MVC 5.

Comment: @RosbergLinhares I quick googled around and found that somebody used it with v4 as well - https://dotnettrace.net/2013/10/01/cross-origin-resource-sharing-using-access-control-allow-origin-in-mvc-4/ . Frankly, I haven't checked this article deeply, so possible that he did something wrong.

Comment: @RredCat In this link the autor is implementing CORS from scratch. I really expressed wrong. I meant that the https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Cors/ package is only compatible with MVC 5.