# Proxy return error 403 forbidden - c#

Tags: c#, http, proxy, httpwebrequest, http-status-code-403

I'm building a proxy, and I want it to return a `403 forbidden` in case the host in the request is found in a "black host list".

I couldn't realize how I can create a "HttpWebResponse" without sending the request
and change the Status Code to 403.

Should I create a request with the given Url

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
```

and do some manipulation on this request, or can I do it other way? Also, which manipulation can I do to get a 403 response?

Thanks :)

Comment: You just need to return to the client a 403 status. How you do this will depend upon how you receive HTTP requests from the proxy user?

Comment: Just ask if the server is in a black hole list and if, you just throw an exception or return anything and say "403".

Comment: I'm receiving it from an object "HttpListenerContext" (saving as context).
I'm taking out the Url
url = context.Request.RawUrl

Compare to the black list
*** until here I implemented all

but the proxy server need to return a "HttpWebResponse"
which in "Non black listed URI"
I got from:
HttpWebResponse response = this.GetResponse(request);

Comment: Have a look here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5649852/asp-net-web-service-i-would-like-to-return-error-403-forbidden

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I added:

```
context.Response.StatusCode = 403; context.Response.Close();
```

In chrome I get an empty page, and don't know why),

and in Internet Explorer I get the default 403 error.